# how to simulate a fluid (not falling)

Tags: physics, fluid-simulation

so i watched a flip fluid simulation and tried it , but its nothing special , the only thing i think folks download it is to get a fluid dropping , which should technically be possible by the default manta flow features in blender , the question is how?? , i tried to look in the flow settings for the starting of the flow , but cant figure out , i was trying to just make water show up from the inflow object for just 1 frame but cant find the way to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'Use Flow' property of the inflow object can be used to enable/disable the flow. For 'Inflow' this controls the generation of fluid and for 'Outflow' objects this controls the removal of fluid from the simulation. 'Use Flow' can be keyframed so to just add fluid on one frame simply keyframe it 'off' until that frame, keyframe it 'on' for that frame and then 'off' on the following frame.

Note that you may need to re-bake the simulation to see the effect of your changes.

Comment: i just didnt have the information about that feature , tq

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want gravity inside your simulation, it is very easy. Inside the physics properties of the domain, scroll down to the bottom at "Field Weights" and drag Gravity to zero.